# jquery progressbar question

Tags: jquery

Im new to jquery and wanted to know how in my jquery code could I show an image on my page if the progressbar = 100?

My code:

```
  $(function () {
                   $("Timer1").enableSelection('enable');
                   $("#progressbar").progressbar({ value: 0 });
                   setTimeout(updateProgress, 200);
                 });
    function updateProgress() {
                   var progress;
                   progress = $("#progressbar")
                                  .progressbar("option", "value");
                   if (progress < 100) {
                                $("#progressbar")
                                       .progressbar("option", "value", progress + 2);
                                setTimeout(updateProgress, 200);
```

My image is called simply image1.

Any ideas? Basically I want to show an image showing that the task has been completed. 
Thanks

Comment: Does that current if condition get hit? If so, just add an else if for `progress === 100`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put your image (*with an id attribute specified*) in the DOM before-hand (*invisible though `display:none`*) and just show the element using the `.show()` method.

The code to show should go to the else part of your if statement

```
if (progress < 100) {
     // whatever you do .....
}
else
{
  $('imgid').show();
}
```

Comment: Hey Gaby, if I do what you said then the jquery doesnt seem to work. I preview it and the code skips jquery and only shows html. Any ideas?  my code looks like this     if (progress < 100) {
                                $("#progressbar")
        .progressbar("option", "value", progress + 2);
                                setTimeout(updateProgress, 200);
                                }
                                else {
                                    $("#progressbar").hide('slow')
  } } }

Comment: @gabrielVa, can you put the code online at some place like [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or another live link where we can see it run .. ?

Comment: Actually I got it to work, i had an extra } Where I shouldn't have had it. I wals also able to add a $("#progressbar").hide('slow'); to give it an extra flare. Thansk for the help Gaby!

Comment: @gabrielVa, anytime. Glad you got it sorted out :)